# How to auto run jar file in Linux (fedora, ubuntu) such as service on Windows

Tags: linux, jar, release

I made executable jar file for release to customers.

For Windows, I made .exe setup file. 
if exe file executed, made jar file installed and auto run on service.

But, I don't know way for release linux like Windows.

I want to setup and then auto run in linux such as made for windows exe file.

Anyone know how to do this?

I found informations like packaging but, these things do not seem to be what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can **create a custom RPM package** which install your executable jar. You can also add steps for installing **systemd** unit file(*init file if on older Linux system*) which will run your jar as service.

These RPMs uses script which specifies what to do while installation. Just add the steps to copy jar to /bin directory and steps to create/install/enable systemd unit file onto system.